# Не могу сделать миграцию в ef core в xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, entity-framework-core

У меня есть проект на Xamarin и хочу использовать EF Core с не локальной БД, создал UserDbContext - потом, я по советам создал отдельное решение и потом уже пишу **add-migration Init**, но выдаёт ошибку

`add-migration : Exception calling "Start" with "1" argument(s): "Exec format error"`, потом подумал перекачать  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools, но оно не выхоидило(пробовал разных версий качать), в итоге скачалось 2.1.0 версии, но ошибка такая-же, что делать?

Comment: БД не делают публичной. БД не должна быть доступна за пределами сервера. Следовательно в мобильных приложениях EF никто не использует вообще - потому что это дыра в безопасности, и очень серьезная. Создайте Web API сервер, который будет внутри себя работать с базой, а с приложениями клиентов через API. Порт БД должен быть открыт только на localhost и больше никуда.

Comment: А есть какая-то статья/видео по этому, хочу разобраться, но не знаю с чего начать

Comment: ASP.NET Core Web API тип проекта.

Comment: Cпасибо, попробую что-то порыскать в этом направлении

Comment: @aepot беда в том, что у меня Visual Studio Mac, и у меня нету ASP.NET Core Web API проекта, что мне делать с этим?

Comment: Все там есть, запустите установщик и включите необходимые компоненты. Вас же не надо учить программы на комп ставить?

Comment: Да, нашел всё что надо, спасибо большое, пойду учить теперь Web Api

Comment: [Design-time DbContext Creation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) - здесь описано, как утилита миграции ищет и создаёт контекст для своей работы. Нужен либо хост, либо конструктор без параметров (а у вас, похоже, с параметром), либо design-time factory.